# I need a way to make sure that words that are given to an array are real words.(RTP-hsa,console)

Tags: java, dictionary, console, spell-checking, spelling

I solved the issue with making sure that only letters in the array are used, now I need a way to import or load a dictionary into the console so fake words can't be used. I had the idea of finding a txt document and load it into an array when the program starts, but I haven't had any luck finding one. If anyone finds a way, please provide a good description of how to load it into the hsa.console form. Thanks. (Java Ready to Program hsa.console)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some that solves the does a word exist.  I wasn't sure how you were storing the array of characters so I guessed it was a 2d array of chars.  The method wordExists is the one used to check if the word exists.  I used a test to check that it worked and it did on multiple inputs. Edit: I just realized that this could cause the words to cycle back onto itself if its a palindrome, ill post the fixed code as soon as I make it

```
public static boolean wordExists(char[] [] characters, String word)
{
    char[] word_as_char = word.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < characters[0].length; j++)
        {
            boolean wordExists = checkWord(characters, word_as_char, 0, i, j);
            if (wordExists)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean checkWord(char[] [] characters, char[] word, int index, int x, int y)
{
    boolean wordExists = false;
    if (index < word.length) {
        if (characters[x] [y] == word[index])
        {
            if (x + 1 < characters.length)
            {
                wordExists = wordExists | checkWord(characters, word, index + 1, x + 1, y);
            }
            if (x - 1 > 0)
            {
                wordExists = wordExists | checkWord(characters, word, index + 1, x - 1, y);
            }
            if (y + 1 < characters[0].length)
            {
                wordExists = wordExists | checkWord(characters, word, index + 1, x, y + 1);
            }
            if (y - 1 > 0)
            {
                wordExists = wordExists | checkWord(characters, word, index + 1, x, y - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    if (index == word.length - 1 && characters[x] [y] == word[index])
    {
        wordExists = true;
    }
    return wordExists;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`CheckLetter != (" ")` doesn't check content equality, it checks reference equality - are these 2 variables referring to the same object. Use `!" ".equals(CheckLetter)`. Better yet, don't use `String` for holding single characters, there is `char` for this and there is `Character` class that has some methods for handling them (like `toUpperCase`).